# RSS feed for Google Search News Tab

Tags: rss, google-search, google-news

There is a difference whether I search for something on `news.google.com`:

[image]

Or on `google.com` -> `News` tab:

[image]

For my purposes I get more useful results on the News tab on `google.com` and I need to know how to create an rss feed by search query. For `news.google.com` I can do it like this:

```
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={query}
```

But what is the right URL format for the `google.com` -> News tab way?

Answer (score 1):

Answer: I don't think it is possible because Google Search is a different service than Google News. Google Search doesn't have a RSS feed.

The only way you can get something similar is `news.google.com` feed is with  `https://www.google.com/search?q={query}&tbm=nws&num=100` which will return the top 100 results from the news tab from Google Search.

`&tbm=nws` will give you the news tab.

`&num=100` will return the top 100 results which I believe Google News RSS feed is returning.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Create alert" button at the bottom of the news page.